# SELECT * FROM videos WHERE url = substring($url, 0, 5)

Tags: php, mysql, get

Usually, the videos url are similar to `site.com/watch?v=abcde.flv`
I would like the new url to be `site.com/watch?v=abcde`

usually its:
    `$url = $_GET['v'];`
and then

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE url = '$url'");
```

how can I use only the first 5 characters?

this is what I've tried and its not working:

```
$newurl = substr($url, 0, 11);
```

and then

```
$query("SELECT FROM videos WHERE substring(url, 0,11) = '$newurl'");
```

Comment: $url = $_GET['v']; $first_five substr($url , 0, 5);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax in SQL for string parsing is :

```
LEFT ( character_expression , integer_expression )
```

See for more info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms177601.aspx

In your case :

```
//assuming your new url of watch?v=abcde
$url = $_GET['v']; 

//assuming the video in your databse is stored as abcde.flv
$query = mysql_query("SELECT FROM videos WHERE LEFT(url,5) = '$url'");
```